# Best way to invest as a beginner at 20 year old

Tags: stocks, investing, starting-out-investing, investment-strategies

I'm 20 year old and I would like to start investing but honestly internet it's full of fake/misleading platform/resources.

My budget it's not very big, I would like to start with around 100 euros but I could raise my budget to **less than 1000 euros** and mine it's a long term goal.
I have seen a lot of platform and way of investment, from the 'classic' stocks to real estate and other type of investment.

I would like to know **which one is the best** and **if it's worth to start with this amount of money** or you need at least 5000 euros or close to that, and what **advice** you would give me **to start investing.**

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that in your position the best investment is **training and education** so that you can get a job which will provide you with a **decent income**. Only then would I start worrying about what happens to the earned money.